# Exceptions from scripting within Biztalk Map

Tags: biztalk, maps, exception

I have a biztalk (2006 R2) map which uses an class to provide for some custom logic that we couldn't achieve neatly through the existing functoids.

When an exception is thrown from one of the methods of this class the exception detail is, unfortunately lost (at least as far as I can see), The transform shape simply throws an exception indicating `'Function 'ScriptNS-:DoFoo()' has failed'`

I've since come to the conclusion that using the Scripting functoids in a map is a recipe for disaster, but thats another discussion.  My question is is there a mechanism to allow the exception detail pass up the  parent orchestration?

Comment: I can't remember the context for this question so I don't know if I solved how to get the exception detail or just fixed the specific exception. But I figured I'd add this if it helps someone else, I know that in biztalk many of the exceptions thrown from the orchestration components are 'wrapped' as the InnerException of the actual exception message you receive..

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the 'System.Diagnostics.Trace' class and output stuff inside the method related to its progress. Start with outputting the input parameters as they might differ from what your method expect.

Simplified example:

```
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("HelperClass XX - Method YY - This was passed from the map : " + inputParamOne);
```

Using a clear naming standard makes it easier to filter inside free tool DebugView, especially when on a machine running more than your stuff. I often leave this tracing in as it often proves invaluable later on. The overhead, if no listener is connected, could normally be ignored.

If you have the map deployed and running on a BizTalk development machine you could debug by performing the following steps:

- Put a breakpoint in the method
- Select 'Debug - Attach To Process'
- Attach to the HostInstance process
  (BTSNTSvc.exe if 32-bit) handling
  your corresponding port or
  orchestration running the map.